# I passed an entire JSON DB to the gpt-4-1106-preview api but it's costing me a lot. How can I optimize it?

Tags: javascript, json, gpt-4

So, I have the following real estate db:

```js
[
  {
    "Bodegas": [
      {
        "file": "....pdf",
        "Tipo Operacion": "Renta",
        "Zona": "HUMBOLDT",
        "Presupuesto Renta": 24000
      },
      {
        "file": "B_R_V_HUMBOLDT (a-s) 715.pdf",
        "Tipo Operacion": "Renta y Venta",
        "Zona": "HUMBOLDT",
        "Presupuesto Renta": 60000,
        "Presupuesto Venta": 11000000
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Houses": [
      {
        "file": "....pdf",
        "Tipo Operacion": "Renta",
        "Zona": "Camino Real Olmedillas",
        "Presupuesto Renta": 13500,
        "Recamaras": 3,
        "Amueblado": false,
        "Mascotas": false,
        "Amenidades": [
          "Cochera 2 autos",
          "2.5 baños",
          "Cocina",
          "Sala de TV",
          "Cuarto de lavado",
          "Cuarto de servicio",
          "Bar"
        ]
      },
      {
        "file": "....pdf",
        "Tipo Operacion": "Renta",
        "Zona": "El Carmen",
        "Presupuesto Renta": 37000,
        "Recamaras": 4,
        "Amueblado": false,
        "Mascotas": false,
        "Amenidades": [
          "Cochera 2 autos",
          "3.5 baños",
          "Cocina",
          "Sala de TV",
          "Área de servicio",
          "2 patios",
          "Biblioteca",
          "Estudio"
        ]
      },
      ...
```

And I'm passing it to the gpt-4-1106-preview api like this:

```js
const fs = require('fs');  // Assuming 'fs' module is required in the actual code

const jsonFile = fs.readFileSync("./db.json", "utf8");
const db = JSON.stringify(jsonFile);

async function sendMessage(message) {
  const chatCompletion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    messages: [
      {
        role: "system",
        content: `
        
        Based on the user's message, choose one of the following options and return only the name of the catalog file that corresponds to the user's search.

        You can return multiple files depending on the user's search:
        
        ${db}
        
        If no file is found, or the user is selling, offering, or it is noticed that they do not request or want a property, return the following message: nothing 

        So ignore the following words: offer, sell, offers, sells, referred, ref 
        
        `,
      },
      {
        role: "user",
        content: message,
      },
    ],
    model: "gpt-4-1106-preview",
  });

  return chatCompletion.choices[0].message.content;
}
```

As you can imagine, this implementation works like a charm for retrieving and searching properties. However, the caveat is that the costs are massive.

How can I reduce the costs or have a context of the db? Pinecone? Langchain?